# What is the correct thread synchronization object in Windows that allows a thread to wait until another thread unblocks it?

Tags: windows, multithreading, events, synchronization

I have a Delphi application running under Windows that needs to block until another thread has delivered data.  In other words, I need to wait on a synchronization object that from a particular thread I can put into the **non-signaled state** as if another thread held ownership of the object, so that when I call **WaitFor()** the thread blocks until one of the other threads unblocks it (there are more than one potential thread that can *unblock* and it is not known in advance which one).  Note, all the threads have access to a shared data area so access to a common synchronization object is not a problem.

I thought **Events** were the right choice until I read this troubling blog post by Raymond Chen on the the problems with PulseEvent():

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/05/346888.aspx

What is the correct synchronization technique to achieve this result?  If you have a link to a Delphi or C/C++ example that would be great.

Comment: Why do you think you want to use PulseEvent over SetEvent?

Comment: @Logan Capaldo.  I don't.  I just was not familiar enough with events to know that PulseEvent was not required to use them.  David's reply below helped me understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are perfectly fine, just don't use PulseEvent. Not only did Microsoft hopelessly botch the implementation, but its use is complicated by inherent race conditions. If the event occurs just before the thread blocks on the event, the event will be lost. Instead, use manual-reset events.

To block:

B1) Set the event to blocking.

B2) Check to make sure the event hasn't occurred yet and be sure you want to block on it. If necessary, put the event in a shared data structure where threads waking us will notice it.

B3) Block on the event.

To wake:

W1) Update shared data to reflect the fact that the event has occurred.

W2) Unblock the event. If necessary, traverse the shared data structure and unblock all events associated with whatever just happened.

Here, there's no race condition. If the event occurs after B1 or B2 but before B3, the block in B3 won't actually block because W2 will unblock it. If the event has already occurred before W1, the thread will never block because B2 will see the effects of W1 and we'll never get to B3.

In most cases, operations B2 and W2 need to be done while holding a lock shared by all threads that handle events of this type.

Comment: Thanks @David Schwartz.  Is a critical section sufficient to protect the B2 and W2 operations?  Also, any thread or app termination tips on shutting down the involved threads (besides making sure all events are unblocked)?

Comment: @RobertOschler Yes, a critical section is fine. Don't shut down the threads. Just code the threads so they shut themselves down when they have no work to do. (And arrange things so they have no work to do when they, well, have no work to do.)

Comment: Some of the threads are coming from DirectShow filters and filter graph operation so I don't always have control of how they shut down.  If you have any DirectShow specific tips I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use auto-reset events. See the parameters of the CreateEvent function. You will need one event for each thread that needs to be waited. Just call SetEvent, and no other functions like PulseEvent or ResetEvent. The WaitFor will automatically reset the event. If the event was already set before you call WaitFor, it will return immediately, resetting the event.